# How to make multiple HTTP calls in Angular6, using forkJoin and ngrx?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6, ngrx-effects

### Scenario

In my angular6 app, i have three cateories, catA, catB, catC.
**Each category needs data from 3 APIs**. On clicking any category it loads the CategoryDetailsComponent, i dispatch action (LoadCategoryDetails).

I have implemented `forjoin` to perform parallel api calls(in service) and also `resolver` to ensure all the calls are done, only then the component should loaded.

### Problem

- On clicking catA (or page reload), `categoryNames` array is empty
- On clicked catB (second routing), `CategoryNames` array shows list of previous category (catA)

Maybe one of the api call is taking time. and my resolver is not configured properly.

### Question

**How to configure effects and resolver??**

**How to use forkjoin to make multiple calls and send data to component?**

### Code

1. dipatch action and subscribe to selector

   ```js
   ngOnInit() {
       const id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('categoryId'), 10);
       this.store.dispatch(new fromCategory.LoadCategoryDetails(id));

       this.store.select(getCategoryDetails)
                 .subscribe((data) => {
                   this.categoryDetails = data[0];
                   this.journeys = data[1];
                   this.categories = data[2];
                 });

       // filter only category name
       // problem
       this.categories.forEach( category => {
         this.categoryNames.push(category.name);
       });
   }
   ```
2. effects (look for action and call service)

   ```js
   @Effect()
   loadCategoryDetails$ = this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType<fromCategory.LoadCategoryDetails>(CategoryActionTypes.LoadCategoryDetails),
       switchMap((action) => {
       return this.categoryService.getCategoryDetails(action.payload).pipe(
           map(data => new fromCategory.LoadCategoryDetailsSuccess(data))
       );
       })
   );
   ```
3. service func making multiple calls and using forkjoin

   ```js
   import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

   getCategoryDetails(categoryId) {
       const categoryDetails = this.http.get(url);
       const journeys = this.http.get(url);
       const courses = this.http.get(url);

       return forkJoin([categoryDetails, journeys, courses]);
   }
   ```
4. resolver

   ```js
   export class CategoryDetailsResolver implements Resolve<any> {

       constructor(
           private categoryService: CategoryService,
           private router: Router) {}

       resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
           const categoryId = route.paramMap.get('categoryId');
           return this.categoryService.getCategoryDetails(categoryId);
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the resolver?  You are basically calling the same http request twice " getCategoryDetails() ", once in the resolver and again when you dispatch the action.

Comment: Another question to ask yourself is what is the scope of the category details state? is it just for that one component or is the state needed across many components or modules? I see many developers over use redux when it is not even appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

refactor your code to NOT use route.snapshot and see if that fixes it.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {

if(data) {
 this.store.dispatch(new fromCategory.LoadCategoryDetails(data.id));

 this.store.select(getCategoryDetails)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.categoryDetails = data[0];
            this.journeys = data[1];
            this.categories = data[2];

 this.categories.forEach( category => {
  this.categoryNames.push(category.name);
  });
});

}

});

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your solution worked, and i am getting live data. Really appreciate your time and effort, to provide the solution.

This solution is `subscribing resolver in the component directly and getting data from service`, but the store/effects is not being used here. Can you please tell how can i **get the data dispatching action** and by subscribing to store selector and not directly from the service/resolver??

Comment: I have [dispathced action in comp](https://imgur.com/a/skiakRI) and [subscribing resolver in effects](https://imgur.com/ggsMEuZ), but it gives [error](https://imgur.com/a/bYeFCaw).

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of **forkjoin** looks fine to me. But one problem I can see in your code is , you are iterating the categories outside of the **getCategoryDetails** callback. Since it is asynchronous , you should always ensure you are getting the categories before you do the iteration. For that you should move the code for iterating the categories to the successful callback function.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('categoryId'), 10);
    this.store.dispatch(new fromCategory.LoadCategoryDetails(id));

    this.store.select(getCategoryDetails)
              .subscribe((data) => {
                this.categoryDetails = data[0];
                this.journeys = data[1];
                this.categories = data[2];

this.categories.forEach( category => {
      this.categoryNames.push(category.name);
    });
              });

    // filter only category name
    // problem

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that and it gives error `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. Can you please check if `effects` is correct? i believe, if resolver is configured properly, this issue might be resolved.

Comment: @Raj check console.log(data[2]) and make sure that you are getting data correctly. The data you are getting could be undefined

Comment: yes data is coming, but initailly it is undefined. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/U2uncKd)

Comment: @Raj You can wrap the same in a condition if(data[2]){ //do the iteration}

Comment: @Raj I hope you have logged inside the successful callback , I think data[2] of undefined is coming somewhere else

Comment: i used condition also `if(data[2]){ //do the iteration}`, but as the api's are not resolved, the old data is still present and i am getting old array. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/6AqtnxV)

Comment: and also did `categoryNames = []` in constructor, to reset the value and load new api data. didn't work.

Comment: @Raj I don't think it's because of your client side code , just check in postman or fiddler you are getting the data you expected

Comment: yes i checked inpostman, there i am getting correct data. **In browser** also i am getting correct, **but delayed**. On route change, the `categoryDetails` array has data from previous router, and that is getting into `categoryNames`.

Comment: @Raj here is your problem: const id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('categoryId'), 10);

avoid using the router snapshot in components that are reused like /app/my-component/:id because the OnInit does not fire as expected. use thie.route.data.subscribe() instead